# How can I do string replace in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$("#title").keyup(function(){
var titleval = $("#title").val();

var res = titleval.replace(" ", "-");

$("#newsurl").val(res);

});
```

to replace spaces into dash to get URL like this

```
wordone-wordtow-wordthree
```

but i have problem with this code it's just replace first space like this

```
wordone-wordtow wordthree
```

How can i solve this problem

Comment: Add corresponding HTML code too

Comment: You will find answer here : **[Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a global match, you can do this with a `regex`

```
var res = titleval.replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

Though `String.prototype.replace` does support having flags passed, this is deprecated in firefox and already doesn't work in chrome/v8.

Comment: BETTER IF, `var res = titleval.replace(/\s+/g, "-");`

Answer (score 2):

Alternate method (if regex is not mandatory) could be to split and join

```
var res = titleval.split(" ").join("-");
```

or

```
var res = titleval.split(/\s+/).join("-");
```

Comment: @Guru, Why `.split` over `.replace` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yes agree, maybe this is truely the most trivial scenario to use split and join over replace. This is just an alternate method to do the same job, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with global flag

```
titleval.replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
$("#title").keyup(function(){
 var titleval = $("#title").val();
 var res = titleval.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
 $("#newsurl").val(res);
});
```